# Can we varied a class name during creating a new object?

Tags: php

I have two classes written on different php file having same name. I want to load one at a time. For this i search many places .. and i found this piece of code. I want can anybody elaborate what does it doing?

```
$class= $this->controller.'Controller_';
$controller=new $class($this->registry);
```

Please explain more if you can ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to a class by using a variable. So in this case, a class name is put together using the value of `$this->controller` and the constant string `'Controller_'`. So if `$this->controller` is `'Foo'`, $class becomes `'FooController_'`. 
The second line instantiates an object of this class and passes a value to it's constructor.

So in the end, this code does:

```
$controller = new FooController_($this->registry);
```

The advantage is, that the 'Foo' part is variable. So for instance, you could map an url path to a class, so that `example.com/foo` is handled by a `fooController` and `example.com/bar` is handled by a `barController`.

So this is not what you want. This is loading different classes with different names.

If you have two classes with the same name, you must make sure that you only load the file of the class you want to use. You cannot use two classes with the same name, unless they are in different namespaces. So if you have two files, foo1.php and foo2.php, and each contains a class named `foo`, then you'll need to include the proper file. But I think this is bad design. Normally you shouldn't have to choose between classes of the same name, unless maybe in a test case, where a unit test can load a mock version of a real class.